# How to test git hooks

Tags: git, git-post-receive

Since "testing" is a common use for a Git hook, my question is hard to search for.

I'm writing a fairly involved git post-receive hook and want to know what the best way to test it is. Currently my process is:

- make changes to post-receive in a dummy "remote" repo
- make a change to a dummy local repo
- commit change in dummy local repo
- push change to dummy remote repo

Is there any easier way to test this? Ideally it would look like:

- make change(s) to post-receive in a dummy repo
- issue "magic" command to test post-receive

Perhaps I can "reissue" a previous push or have the remote repo act as though it just received a push with a specific hash?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Write a hook that just records its arguments/environment and dumps that to a file. Then you can just re-invoke the real hook at your leisure with the same environment/arguments and it will act as though you just re-issued the exact same push.

Comment: That's about what I did but instead by manually inspecting (echoing) the relevant variables.

Comment: what would such a "dumper" hook look like?

Comment: @JonWatson, I just used `echo $@;echo; pwd; echo; set`

Comment: This may be obvious to some, but ensure your hook script is **executable**!  I created mine in a text editor, rather than copying the .sample, and it did not execute.

Answer (score 20):

Answer this four-years-old question.

If you'd like to test hook, you need to test in local environment first, I give the detail commands for following up, use `post-receive` as sample:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/hook_test
$ cd /tmp/hook_test

# set local git repo, where you put hooks in it.
$ git clone --bare https://github.com/git/git.git

# set develop environment which is cloned from the new created repo. 
$ git clone git.git repo 
    
# copy and rename the hook you need test to "post-receive"
$ cd git.git/hooks
$ cp ~/post-receive-test post-receive

# suppose the hook script is bash script.
# edit "post-receive" and add "set -x" to second line in it to active debug

$ cd /tmp/hook_test/repo
# emulate a hook trigger, do some changes, "git add" and "git commit" it 

$ git push
 
# Now you should see the script "post-receive" runs automatically with debug details.
```

You should be free to run `git push`, that the updates are only pushed to local repo `/tmp/hook_test/git.git`

Answer (score 7):

My approach is to dial the HEAD at the remote repo back one commit, and then push again:

```
ssh <repo> 'cd /<repo_path>; git update-ref refs/heads/master HEAD^' && git push origin master
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

For debugging you could also end your hook in something like this:

```
echo "No errors found."
exit 1
```

If you are happy with you hook you of course take out the last line again.